# How to control the order that CMAKE builds subdirectories when involving options?

Tags: cmake

I know that CMake automatically somehow figures out the dependency tree.  It will build things in the right order normally.

I decided to use options and that has caused it to guess poorly.

I have a variant of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439865/in-cmake-how-to-specify-dependencies-of-subdirectories-in-a-scalable-way?rq=1) following:

```
/CMakeLists.txt
  /src/CMakeLists.txt
  /testpackage1/CMakeLists.txt
  /testpackage2/CMakeLists.txt
```

In my case, mylib has two kinds -- a static and a dynamic.

```
OPTION(MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC "Build static library" TRUE)
IF(MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC)
    ADD_LIBRARY(mylib_static STATIC ${MyLib_SRCS})
    ...
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mylib_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "mylib")
    SET(MYLIB_LIB_TARGET mylib_static)
ENDIF(MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC)


OPTION(MYLIB_BUILD_SHARED "Build shared library" TRUE)
IF(MYLIB_BUILD_SHARED)
    ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED ${MyLib_SRCS})
    ...
    SET(MYLIB_LIB_TARGET mylib)
ENDIF(MYLIB_BUILD_SHARED)
```

At this point `${MYLIB_LIB_TARGET}` has either `mylib` or `mylib_static` in it

In the unit test packages....

```
OPTION(MYLIB_BUILD_TEST "Build test program." TRUE)
IF(MYLIB_BUILD_TEST)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MYLIB_SOURCE_DIR})
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_mylib main.c)
    IF(NOT MYLIB_LIB_TARGET)
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB_LIB_TARGET is not specified")
    ENDIF() 
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_mylib ${MYLIB_LIB_TARGET})
ENDIF(MYLIB_BUILD_TEST)
```

In the parent:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("testpackage1")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("testpackage2")
```

What I get is: `MYLIB_LIB_TARGET is not specified` from the unit test project

I think it's because the options are messing with the automatic dependency tree logic in CMake.

Comment: Where you state "At this point.." what value has `MYLIB_LIB_TARGET`? Can you check with `message("actual value: ${MYLIB_LIB_TARGET}")` and tell us the output? Maybe the same before you check in in the unit test.

Comment: It tends to run the test projects first.  I get the FATAL_ERROR and it never gets into the part where it says "At this point".

Comment: Have you included the subdirectory too early? Difficult to tell. Can you reduce your project to the bare minimum and post more complete files?

Comment: Probably you need to call SET(MYLIB_LIB_TARGET mylib PARENT_SCOPE) that will ensure the variable exists in your test packages. It looks to me like you're setting a CMake variable in one file and expecting it to exits in a parallel file. Variable scope exists in the current CMakeLists.txt and all subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt files. As stated above, message() is you friend here.